# What is the syntax for InsertedTextColor

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I want track changes in my ms word 2016 file to have Insertions as Red, and Deletions as Violet

When I give

```
ActiveDocument.InsertedTextColor = wdRed
ActiveDocument.DeletedTextColor = wdViolet
```

it throws an error.

What is the correct syntax for addressing InsertedTextColor and DeletedTextColor?

runtime error: 438 
object doesn't support this property or method.

(previously only Red and Violet was written, edited that to prefix with wd)

Comment: It is probably `vbRed` and `vbViolet`, but it would be handy to include the error message. Also, this is one of the few good uses for the macro recorder. Record a macro of manually changing the color of the cell to the color you want and let it show you the exact verbiage to use.

Comment: yes colore names were wrong. I changed that, thanks for the tip.

but it is still now working. error added above.

Comment: `ActiveDocument` doesn't support the `InsertedTextColor` property. There is another object layer or two or three in there. Use the macro recorder or the Object Explorer to find the fully qualified path to the property.